# Select с множественным выбором

Tags: html, select2

Нужно написать выпадающий список, так чтобы пользователь мог отметить несколько значений.

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="admission" name="admission[]" id="select" class="select">
  <option disabled>Выберите</option>
  <option value="XXX1">XXX1</option>
  <option value="XXX2">XXX2</option>
  <option value="XXX3">XXX3</option>
  <option value="XXX4">XXX4</option>
</select>
```

Такое решение срабатывает только если зажать клавиши ctrl/shift, это не очень удобно. есть решение чтобы можно было просто щелкать по пунктам списка и эти значения оставались выбранными?
Либо сделать такой выпадающий список , где пункты можно отмечать галочками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В бутстрапе есть такое решение. Вот [примеры](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) с самого сайта.

Подключите `bootstrap` к сайту.

> И еще одно. Корректная версия для работы плагина `bootstrap 3.3.2`.

На `Bootstrap 4` нужно переделать.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```